# How can I change Places under 'Computer' in Nautilus

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, places

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove the Nautilus bookmarks?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79150/how-to-remove-the-nautilus-bookmarks)

in nautilus side pane (places view), you have the sections 'Bookmarks', 'Computer' and 'Network'. I cant rename or remove any entries in 'Computer'.

I have all my Music / Documents etc on my NAS and not locally under my 'Home'.

How can I get rid of those entries?

*ps. I'm running gnome3 on Ubuntun 11.10 and it's just SWEET ;-)*