# How do I remove 'Places' entries from the Nautilus sidebar?

Tags: nautilus

I want to remove Videos and Music from the left side panel. But, I can't seem to find the option to do so. How do you do that?

[image]

Comment: I was able to rename them in the side pane by just renaming each folder in the main pane. Highlight, press F2, rename. You might try making a symlink to your NAS folders and putting that in your Home folder, replacing the unneeded default folders. Right-click a destination folder, choose 'Make link', and drag the link into the home folder. Rename it Music or whatever, and replace the defaults.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS Better bring it up to the GNOME devs.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

<sup>Tested in Ubuntu 14.04</sup>

Those bookmarks are controlled by `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and commenting out a lines configures the appearance of the list

As an example, to remove the Videos bookmark from the list change the line:

```
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

to

```
#XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

**Note:**
After login the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` gets reverted to the original set by `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults`. To prevent that make the file "read-only" either by right clicking and then **properties** > **permissions** or using the command

```
chmod -w ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

If you need to edit the file again do the opposite via Nautilus or use the command

```
chmod +w ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

If you want to apply this to all users in your system change the file `vim /etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf` and set the option `enabled` to `False`. You need root permissions or this.

Comment: is this the same file as user-dirs.dirs file that is located at: /home/USERNAME/.config/user-dirs.dirs ? I cant find a DIR that is located at ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs

Comment: Commenting out is *not* the right solution (let alone changing the file permissions). Instead set e.g. `XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME"` to disable the videos user directory as other answers suggest. For a source, see http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/#settings .

Comment: This doesn't work (for me, at least) on 16.04.  @Ben's answer below does work.

Comment: Didn't work on pop os 21.04

Comment: @KirillStarostin and everybody else: also see the comments concerning `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` in this answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/762597/1033332 this helped me with impish indri 21.10

Comment: on my Ubuntu 20.04 doing `chmod -w ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` stops the user account from logging into xwindows.

Comment: Note: it does not work for 20.04, the write permission will be restored after re-login.  Instead set e.g. `XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME"` will be worked well as other answer suggested.

Answer (score 60):

Open the file `user-dirs.dirs` in your `~/.config` folder with your favorite text editor.

Comment out the line about the folder, which you do not want to be in the nautilus left pane. I commented about the Videos folder.

```
..........
..........
.........
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
#XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Then open a terminal, and run `xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update`, see the magic.

#### for 13.04 or later:

In Nautilus >= 3.6 this will not survive a logout/login or reboot. To overcome this we have to point our `XDG` directories to `"$HOME"` like e.g.:

```
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME"
```

Comment: This one should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Agreed, the best answer! TY very much.

Comment: I have been looking for this for a while. Great answer. Mark as correct @jokerdino

Comment: ...until you reboot! The way around this is to point the folder to $HOME this sticks :)

Comment: 1.5 years later: found a more definitive solution (see below).

Comment: These answers don't work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3494047 What happens when you follow this?

Comment: @Anwar actually it seems to have worked while I was not paying attention. I guess a restart did it?

Answer (score 51):

Aha - the definitive ~answer~ work-around, thanks to *A. J. McMinn*: [Removing entries from Nautilus Places](http://jamesmcminn.com/2012/12/removing-entries-from-nautilus-3-6-places/)

1. Comment out the unwanted bookmarks in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`
2. Make or edit a `~/.config/user-dirs.conf` file and add the entry `enabled=false`.

This solution persists over boot.

---

*...this could be done with a one-liner: `echo "enabled=false" > ~/.config/user-dirs.conf`

Comment: the `enabled=false` flag in `~/.config/user-dirs.conf` is the intended way to do this, the `chmod -w` way suggested by @Bruno Pereira is a workaround.

Comment: This works in 16.04, but not until you log in again.

Comment: This works on 16.04 and survived a reboot. Thanks!!!

Comment: Confirmed in 16.04LTS

Comment: Actually for 16.04, a log out/log in suffices; no need for full reboot, saves you a few seconds ;-)

Comment: I have upvoted this, but it ought to be called the definitive work-round, not the definitive answer. If you want the variables set that point to each well-known directory, but you don't want them as nautilus bookmarks, there is still no solution (other than fixing the hard-coding in nautilus). For instance, if I remove the 'Pictures' bookmark from nautilus in this way, it also breaks the PrtSc key, because the `$XDG_PICTURES_DIR` variable is empty.

Comment: Does not work on 20.04

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.04 for me

Comment: Works on Pop Os 21.04, thank you! Though all the files at home are now on the desktop.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. Without the ~/.config/user-dirs.conf "enabled=false" line the original lines in  ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs are restored on reboot (I took a step-wise approach to testing the mod so observed this). Using user-dirs.conf enabled=false after reboot the unwanted default folders (e.g., Pictures, Videos, etc.) commented out in user-dirs.conf had been moved down in the Nautilus Sidebar and now allowed me to right-click on each and Remove them, the change then persisting on following reboots. Now my own bookmarks have their rightful prominence, grin.

Answer (score 7):

These directories are set by [xdg-user-dirs](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs).

Reading the documentation shows that you can disable a user directory by pointing it to your home directory. Use Ubuntu-Tweak or manually edit the file ~/.conf/user-dirs.dirs and point all the bookmarks you do not want to see to your home dir, and they will also disappear from the Nautilus side bar.

**NOTE:** I tried commenting out and removing the lines from ~/.conf/user-dirs.dirs as forestpiskie suggests, and that worked only until the next time I logged in.  By setting them to the $HOME dir, the settings stuck.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make the modifications you want to *~/.config/user-dirs.dirs* like
   comment out the directories you don not want for example.
2. For the changes not to be reverted at login, you can execute in your terminal `echo "enabled=false" > ~/.config/user-dirs.conf` which will create the *user-dirs.conf* file containing the option `enable=false`.
3. Test the changes and their persistence by logging out and in again. Nautilus should display :

[image: display]

Comment: Personally, from all the answers out here, this one is the only one that worked.

Comment: This is a copy of Ben's answer.

Answer (score 3):

These steps still seem to work in 18.04. Based on comments in this thread I made the following bash script that performs the task. Note, you still need to restart nautilus and right-click remove the items after executing these commands:

```
nautilus_hide_unwanted_sidebar_items()
{    
    echo "Removing unwanted nautilus sidebar items"

    if [ "1" == "0" ]; then
        # Sidebar items are governed by files in $HOME and /etc
        ls ~/.config/user-dirs*
        ls /etc/xdg/user-dirs*

        cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs 
        cat ~/.config/user-dirs.locale

        cat /etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf 
        cat /etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults 

        #cat ~/.config/user-dirs.conf 
    fi

    ### --------------------------------------
    ### modify local config files in $HOME/.config
    ### --------------------------------------

    chmod u+w ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
    #sed -i 's/XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR/#XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR/' ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
    sed -i 's/XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR/#XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR/' ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs 
    sed -i 's/XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR/#XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR/' ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
    sed -i 's/XDG_MUSIC_DIR/#XDG_MUSIC_DIR/' ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
    sed -i 's/XDG_PICTURES_DIR/#XDG_PICTURES_DIR/' ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
    sed -i 's/XDG_VIDEOS_DIR/#XDG_VIDEOS_DIR/' ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
    ###
    echo "enabled=true" >> ~/.config/user-dirs.conf
    chmod u-w ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs

    ### --------------------------------------
    ### Modify global config files in /etc/xdg
    ### --------------------------------------

    #sudo sed -i 's/DOCUMENTS/#DOCUMENTS/'     /etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults 
    sudo sed -i 's/TEMPLATES/#TEMPLATES/'     /etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults 
    sudo sed -i 's/PUBLICSHARE/#PUBLICSHARE/' /etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults 
    sudo sed -i 's/MUSIC/#MUSIC/'             /etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults 
    sudo sed -i 's/PICTURES/#PICTURES/'       /etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults 
    sudo sed -i 's/VIDEOS/#VIDEOS/'           /etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults 
    ###
    sudo sed -i "s/enabled=true/enabled=false/" /etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf
    sudo echo "enabled=false" >> /etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf
    sudo sed -i "s/enabled=true/enabled=false/" /etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf

    # Trigger an update
    xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update

    echo "
    NOTE:
        After restarting nautilus the unwanted items will be demoted to regular
        bookmarks. You can now removed them via the right click context menu.
    "
}
```

Comment: Works with Ubuntu 20.04, Thanks!

Comment: @Quasímodo it's a block comment, similar to `#if 0` in C. Look at the items inside it. It's just acting as notes giving the commands to inspect the files of interest. It works nicely with copy / paste unlike inline comments.

Answer (score 0):

Edit -

Dug into it a bit further - if you edit ~/.config/user-dirs.dir you can remove them from the panel and still have them as folders in your /home it seems.

[image]

Comment: I have tried that. It doesn't work.

Comment: Tried which - the old that I removed or this?

Comment: That removes the special folder functions also from the system ie: downloads will not be selected as download folder anymore, pictures will not be the default folder when using image programs, I really dont advise you on doing that @jokerdino.

Comment: @brunopereira81 Are default directories the only thing this will change? Or might there be other, more drastic things?

Comment: It will change more then just the default directories I think, thats why the warning, you can ofc set it back to how it was but that file is used to set up which directories you want to use for those functions, remove a directory, remove a function.

Comment: Thanks for the details - I'll know a bit more next time.

Answer (score -1):

try going on Bookmarks in window menu, **bookmarks > modify bookmarks** (translate from italian ubuntu) and the remove the one that you don't want

otherwise Ctrl + D to access the menu

Comment: This doesn't work on Places anymore last I tried on Ubuntu 13.04. Editing the user-dirs.dirs as suggested above worked for me though.