# Create a link to a folder on the left panel of Nautilus file manager?

Tags: nautilus, directory

I would like to create a link to some new folder that I have in my home.
The left panel shows docs, images downloads etc. But I would like to add my other folders that I created myself like university etc,

It use to be as simple as drag and drop the folder on the panel, but it doens't work anymore. How can I create a link?

The image is to show what panel I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You can add **Bookmarks**. Just go to the desired directory and via **Global Menu →
Bookmarks → Add bookmark**.

Or you can use simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> when you are in the desired directory.

For Ubuntu 13.04 or more updated versions, you can click the "gear" icon on top right and use "Add Bookmark"

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Adding the bookmark does not add any folder to the side panel.

Comment: The question owner wants to *link* a directory to left side bar. Adding bookmark is the easiest way if I did not misunderstand him/her. What do you mean by "adding folder"?

Comment: Adding a bookmark does not add a link to the folder in the side panel. Sorry for the poor wording in the first comment. You might find this question useful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/79150/how-to-remove-the-nautilus-bookmarks

Comment: If you mean the places below "Computer" by saying folder yes Bookmarks are not shown there. And if question owner asks only for this place below Computer that means I misunderstood him/her.

Comment: that a great way around @heartsmagic it works for me.  But for the sake of the question i wanted to add a folder bookmark under computer

here is how it looks (how can i put an image in the comment?)
![Valid XHTML](/home/riccardo/Immagini/screen).

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood you as @jokerdino guessed. I don't know an easy way to add a bookmark or directory link to add there, sorry. For me, adding bookmarks is a good alternative. For putting an image to your comment, upload your image to http://imgur.com/ and put the link here.

Comment: This worked for me. Adding a bookmark also adds the folder to other windows, such as the save a file window.

Comment: This option seems to have been removed on Ubuntu 13.04. Anyone know how to do it on 13.04?

Comment: Found it: On Ubuntu 13.04 you need to click on the gears icon in the upper right of the window and select Add Bookmark.

Comment: Thanks, Ctrl+D worked in Ubuntu 18.04. However, unlike in 16.04, clicking on the left pane shortcut doesn't mount an unmounted drive partition, which rather has to be done by going to "Other Locations" and mounting from there. Any workaround to this?

Comment: @thephoenix01, I think it is not possible right now. This is probably because of Other Locations do that.

Comment: 18.04 > browse to desired folder > click the 3 line menu icon at the top of the nautilus window > click bookmark this location. Just done this and it does add a new item to the side menu which takes me to the desired files.

Comment: @thephoenix01 you can mount at startup but it doesn't solve the unmount part. Not sure how you would go about that without building a gnome extension to over-ride the default behaviour.

Answer (score 12):

For Ubuntu 17.10, you can create links to the sidebar in the bookmarks file. In the terminal, type

```
cd .config/gtk-3.0
```

Then  open a file called bookmarks with your choice of text editor. I use vim, so I type

```
vim bookmarks
```

Add the link to the directory (folder), save, and do a restart or log off/login.

Comment: just did this on 18.04.1 and it worked. Just commenting for someone who might be looking for it. Thanks.

Comment: **Works on 19.10 also**. In addition, you can **change the visualized name**, adding it as last rule after a space, in this way: `file:///path/to/folder visualized-name`. For example, to show a "projects" folder uppercase, write this: `file:///srv/projects Projects`

Comment: This is a better answer because "Global Menu → Bookmarks → Add bookmark" doesn't tell me what the Global Menu is or how to access it!

Answer (score 2):

it's very easy:

1.Open your folder
2.from menu bar select bookmark
3.select bookmark this location

Comment: where is this menu bar

Comment: Or just open folder. Ctrl-D.

Answer (score 1):

It's not elegant, but if you simply create an empty file, open it, save-as, then browse the top level folder of the directory you want to bookmark in the side panel, you can actually drag that link to the side panel and it will then show up in the side panel.

Comment: It did not work. Can you explain better?

Answer (score 1):

For some Ubuntu version, you can go the parent directory and drag the desired folder to the left panel.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+D didn't work for me. But

```
sudo vi ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks
```

did the job.