# How do I remove default "Places" in Nautilus 3.5?

Tags: nautilus, 12.10, places

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove bookmarks from the Nautilus sidebar?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79150/how-to-remove-bookmarks-from-the-nautilus-sidebar)

Is there a way to remove default "Places" (like Documents, Music, Pictures etc) in Nautilus in Ubuntu 12.10?

Option "remove" in Nautilus context menu is greyed out for these places -- so I can remove the folder itself, but I cannot remove from 'places' the shortcut to it. I have also tried commenting out appropriate lines in the `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file, but it seems to be of no effect either.