# How to remove unwanted default bookmarks in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, 16.04

Nautilus has some bookmarks in the left-hand bar by default. I do not store any music or videos on my computer, and would like those book marks to disappear. How can I make this happen? The linked question has not been updated to include 16.04 and the answers there do not include the fact that the file in `~/.config/` gets re-written upon log-in.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The is no setting for this in Nautilus preferences or gesettings. Instead, the default bookarks are hard-coded be built from `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.

It's not enough to just edit`~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`, however, since the directory list is rebuilt on login from `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults`.

The solution is to comment out the directories that you do not want to show in Nautilus from both `user-dir` files. After logging out and back in, the unwanted bookmarks go away.

Testing showed that you need to edit both files. Only editing one or the other was not enough.

The easiest way to edit the file in `/etc` is to use `sudo` with a textual mode editor, such as `sudo nano /etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults`.

Comment: For me, it was `nano ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`

Comment: when editing `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` one has to remove unwanted lines and not put a `#` in front of it (as can be done in other files). Doing otherwise gives you a (almost certainly hidden) segmentation fault when starting nautilus

Comment: @chaskes is there an option not to remove them but move them beneath the custom bookmarks?