# How to remove default bookmarks from the "Files" in Ubuntu 20.04 (Nautilus)

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, default

By Default in the nautilus for Ubuntu 20.04 (called "Files") I have a number of default bookmarks

- Starred & Recent

  - "Starred" can be removed using this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194319/can-the-starred-folder-in-the-left-pane-of-files-nautilus-be-removed)
  - same guide claims to help removing "Recent", but it doesn't work.
- Default locations: Desktop, Downloads, Pictures, etc

  - can be removed by modifying `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762591/how-to-remove-unwanted-default-bookmarks-in-nautilus)

    - make sure you switch off auto-rollback by `echo "enabled=False" > ~/.config/user-dirs.conf`, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207854/126119)
- Trash

  - haven't found any info on how to remove it.

Two questions:

a) how can I still get rid of "Recent" and "Trash"

b) Is there a better way? `dconf`, `gnome.settings` or such?

Comment: I guess trash is necessary there so maybe it is maindatory

Comment: Same guide *does not* claim to remove "Recent". That is removed when disabling File History in the "Privacy" settings.

Answer (score 1):

The item "Recent" is removed when you disable "File History" under "File History & Trash" in the "Privacy" settings.

You still could also remove "Other locations" by changing "show-other-locations" to "False", i.e. `<property name="show-other-locations">False</property>` in the resource description (cfr. [Can the "Starred" folder be removed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194319/can-the-starred-folder-in-the-left-pane-of-files-nautilus-be-removed/1248774?noredirect=1#comment2194244_1248774)).

I am not aware of any possibility to remove the "Trash" icon without going into the source code itself.

Comment: nice. I got rid of "recent", although this is clearly not the ideal solution. I'm not sure what other applications rely on recent files. It's probably, mostly irrelevant, but nonetheless.

Comment: gotta love how there's a full manual with pictures on fixing the source code https://askubuntu.com/a/351533/308869

Comment: Yes, other GTK apps do. You indeed remove functionality along, unfortunatelly.