# Change nautilus' side bar on all applications that call it

Tags: nautilus

I want to remove a few items from Nautilus' side bar. And other applications, like gmail, use the default file manager on my computer (which happens to be nautilus). I want for the items to disappear when I'm using gmail as well. Therefore answers like [How to remove default bookmarks from the "Files" in Ubuntu 20.04 (Nautilus)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1292300/how-to-remove-default-bookmarks-from-the-files-in-ubuntu-20-04-nautilus) don't seem to work for me, because it only seems to work when I'm using nautilus itself, but not when I'm using a browser.

[image: Nautilus sidebar]

That's the sidebar for my Nautilus right now. You'll notice that it doesn't have the "Pictures", "Music" and some other stuff that it usually has. That's because I edited the file `$HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. That's how it looks right now:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
#XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
```

I'm assuming Nautilus reads this file and uses it to know what to show on the sidebar. I think the folders "Public" and "Templates" don't show up because I don't have them on my computer, and Nautilus is smart enough to not show them. Now, what I really want is to remove "Desktop" and "Trash" from it, but they aren't on the config file. Is it possible? I tried to look on my computer for other configurations Nautilus might use but found nothing.

Comment: In the title, what do you mean by "all applications that call it"? You mean the dialogs that appear when you select File - Open or Save in an application? That is not the file manager. Same as with the others, Desktop and Downloads can be removed by removing them from user-dirs.dir, but they will also loose their "special status", as with any items you remove from the left bar. It is unfortunatelly not more configurable, but that is how it is. You can remove the sidebar with F9 if you do not want to use it at all.

Comment: My situation is a little bit more complicated, but thanks. I'm actually deploying a k9 container and launching a browser on it, and that's all the user can see. Since I block a few folders from the user I want to hide them so it doesn't show an error when he tried to click on them. F9 doesn't really do it for me. I think the only way to achieve what I want would be to change the source code.