# Create custom link in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

In Nautilus (18.04) I have Recent, Home, Desktop, Documents,, Downloads ... links on the left pane.

I never use music, Pictures and Videos. I wonder if it is possible to remove those links, and if it is possible to set something else instead.

I have to go a lot to /opt/lampp/htdocs. It would be nice to have a link sites instead of videos.

Is it possible, and how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Removing these links is easy, and has been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79150/how-to-remove-bookmarks-from-the-nautilus-sidebar).

Among the many answers there, the cleanest approach may be to

1. delete each entry in .config/user-dirs.dirs. Better yet, comment each line out - place a `#` before each line. This way, you can restore the previous state easily if you change your mind.
2. Make the change persistent by disabling an automatic update of this file: create a file .config/user-dirs.conf and add a line `enabled=false`. You can actually do this in a very quick way with a single command: `echo "enabled=false" > ~/.config/user-dirs.conf`

Alternatively, set each entry to "$HOME" to have the bookmarks disappear.

I did not succeed in adding custom links to these "special folders". However, for practical purposes, regular bookmarks, that appear in the section below the special folders, work equally well. For example, to add a bookmark to `/opt/lampp/htdocs`, navigate to that folder and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to add the folder as a bookmark. It immediately appears in the left pane in the bookmark section. Right-click the bookmark and select *Remove* to remove it again.