# how to add location icon to files app

Tags: 18.04, files

Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS has a desktop app called 'Files'; it offers a gui for file browsing.  The left side of this files app has a vertical menu of default locations to view.  I want to add a directory in my home folder to this list.  How to do this?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/79150/how-to-remove-bookmarks-from-the-nautilus-sidebar/79155#79155

Answer (score 1):

Files has the "Bookmarks" feature. Move into the folder to which you want to have quick access from the left side. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. This "bookmarks" the folder, adding it to the left side.

For users of Ubuntu 19.10 and later, a bookmark may also be set from right-clicking the folder button in the top and selecting "Add to Bookmarks". Ubuntu 18.04 also will have it somewhere in a right-click menu, but I cannot currently test.

In general, you can learn about all available shortcut keys from the menu (button with 3 vertical dots): "Keyboard Shortcuts", or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd>.