# How do I programatically add/remove items from Nautilus bookmarks?

Tags: scripts, nautilus

I want to remove Documents, Music, Pictures, Videos and add cloud to my Nautilus bookmarks as part of an user setup script.

How do I edit the bookmarks via the CLI?

[image: Screenshot of Nautilus's sidebar]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove bookmarks from the Nautilus sidebar?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79150/how-to-remove-bookmarks-from-the-nautilus-sidebar)

Comment: @mikewhatever No, it does not provide a way to add anything to the bookmarks. It only handles user dirs (Home, Downloads, Documents, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those bookmarks are controlled by `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and adding new items configures the appearance of the list.

As an example, to add a *Cloud* bookmark from the list add a line:

```
XDG_CLOUD_DIR="$HOME/PATHTOCLOUD"
```