# How does Nautilus populate the list with shortcuts in the top right corner?

Tags: nautilus

My Nautilus is showing the "Desktop" entry twice. I assume that it is using some kind of configuration mechanism, maybe there is a `.desktop` file sitting somewhere in my home folder that is creating this but I am not sure where to look.

So which file locations or dconf keys is nautilus using to populate this list?

[image: Nautilus Top-Right Shortcut List]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit them by modifying `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.

Moreover, you can also check if the second Desktop link is a bookmark by opening the bookmarks file in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`.

According to [How do I remove 'Places' entries from the Nautilus sidebar?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79150/) `user-dirs.dirs` file is generated from the `user-dirs*` files in `/etc/xdg`.

Comment: I am aware of the bookmarks section but the screenshot is taken from above that section and seems to be managed in a different way. Nevertheless I checked and there is no "bookmark" pointing to the desktop in the `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` file. The `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file contains an entry for `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR` pointing to the desktop but that does not explain why I see the `Desktop` entry twice.

Comment: Also bookmarks can be removed by right clicking on them, but the entries from the screenshot cannot be removed via the context menu.

Comment: Edited my answers. alternatively: if you do a backup of ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs (so that in case of troubles you can restore it) and then you delete it, is it regenerated after a boot (or a longout/login)?

Comment: @lanoxx From the icons it seems that you've made Desktop as the default Download folder. Check `XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR` in  `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.

Comment: Indeed, that was it, feels a bit strange that when Downloads points to Desktop that the entry is automatically renamed to `Desktop` instead of remaining at the label `Downloads`. I restored that and now its ok.

Answer (score 2):

The following screenshot shows one of the "Desktop" entries to be renamed to "Download" after I changed the entry `XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR` to something different than `$HOME/Desktop`. As can be seen, the *Desktop* entry with the downward arrow changed its label back to *Downloads*.

[image: Nautilus shortcuts]