# I want to remove permanent links/bookmarks to folders "Downloads", "Videos", etc from folder sidebar view

Tags: directory

I'm not editing my own bookmarks. I want to remove the system provided links on the folder view sidebar to the following folders Pictures, Videos, Downloads, Templates, Documents. I just want Desktop and Home in the list. Someone told me earlier to edit the file user-dirs.dirs in .config. I did that and it worked great. Now since reloading the OS 20.04 that file just re-writes itself every boot with all the links present again. Also the answer with that suggestion of editing user-dirs.dirs is also missing from the forum.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove 'Places' entries from the Nautilus sidebar?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79150/how-do-i-remove-places-entries-from-the-nautilus-sidebar)

Answer (score -2):

Ok. I had to open a terminal and change the permissions to 777 on the user-dirs.dirs file. That worked! Thank you to whoever posted this answer that now seems missing. Thankfully, I was able to remember it.

Comment: 777 is too high. Use chown instead.

Comment: Using 777 permissions makes your system insecure. I don't understand what you were trying to do but this is not the way to achieve it

Comment: See this answer for a good way: https://askubuntu.com/a/407940/558158