# How to pin the downloads, vides, pictures, ect folders to "My Computer"

Tags: 20.04

I decided to delete a ton of stuff from my home folder and afterward most of the folders that were previously under "My Computer" were just gone, but still available through the home folder. How do i return these folders to the My Computer dropdown in the file manager?

I am on ubuntu 20.04 (as tagged)

[image]

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Which file manager are you using? Please add these information [in your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1395673/edit)

Comment: See [this question and **all its answers**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79150/how-do-i-remove-places-entries-from-the-nautilus-sidebar)