# Accidently removed pictures folder

Tags: command-line, filesystem

Hello I accidently deleted the pictures folder and retsored it but now it is not appearing in navigation bar.

Attaching the image The folder is restored but it is not showing in navigation bar along with home,music etc

[image]

[image]

[image]
Thanks kenn for resolving the issue.

Comment: I am using the latest version 22.04 LTS

Comment: Yes but nothing happened

Comment: "Yes" you added the line and nothing happened

Comment: There are a couple of questions already answered on this subject, but I can’t get them to work on 22.04. What version of Ubuntu are you using? There are some answers here https://askubuntu.com/questions/79150/how-do-i-remove-places-entries-from-the-nautilus-sidebar that might help.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64

Comment: run this in terminal `xdg-user-dirs-update --set PICTURES ~/Pictures`

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text files. Copy and paste the content directly in the question and then format the pasted text as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window. You can also copy the output from a terminal using a mouse.

Comment: The screenshot of the `cat user-dirs.dirs` show an existing line: `XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/"`. Try editing this line and make it point to the correct folder: `XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"`. Rather than adding a new line.

Comment: Hi kenn. Thanks for helping me.Your code worked perfectly and restored my pictures folder.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the new `~/Pictures` directory in Nautilus and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: Hello,I am new to Linux.Please explain me what is nautiles.

Comment: @MohulChakraborty "Nautilus" is the file manager you're using. Ubuntu's GUI calls it "Files."

Comment: @MDeBusk - I don’t think that’s quite the same - I think that adds the directory to the lower (bookmarks) section of the left side. It’s not far off what is wanted, but I’m interested to see if there’s a way to restore the original feature. The previous questions have answers that don’t work on 22.04. I wonder if those files are now obsolete as editing them doesn’t seem to change anything.

Comment: @Will It's not quite the same, no, but it gets the OP something of what they lost and it's easy to do. Considering the difficulty they're having with other approaches, I thought it best to mention it.

I suspect, but only suspect, that the OP has yet to log out and back in after editing the file. They don't seem to be obsolete here; I messed one of them up a few weeks ago and my startup files failed to be read until I realized what I'd done wrong.